# Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED... Flutter App

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Good day everyone, I know this question has been asked multiple times but they don't work for me. I am try to run my app and I get the error:

```
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: 
/data/app/vmdl983417249.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #220): 
com.microsoft.appcenter.distribute.DeepLinkActivity: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) 
requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]
```

The solutions I see say to add the `android:exported="true"`  to my AndroidManifest file. I already have this in place. Here is a snippet from my Manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="20"
    android:versionName="1.0.20"
    package="com.org.app_name"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

   <application
        android:label="AppName"
        tools:replace="android:label"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
      />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Does anyone know why I still have this error and can't run my app?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: In your manifest.xml

```
   <activity
        android:exported="true"
        android:name="com.microsoft.appcenter.distribute.DeepLinkActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
        <intent-filter>
        ......
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```